# Why I'm getting crash when I'm trying to set float numbers?

Tags: crash, numbers

I wrote a small calculator program, and when I try to set float numbers it gives me the following crash log:

```
**Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
    at Main.main(Main.java:9)
Process finished with exit code 1**
```

My code is :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the calculator program: " );
        System.out.println( "\n Please enter 2 numbers :");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        float number1 = scanner.nextInt();
        float number2 = scanner.nextInt();
        float sumOfNumbers = number1 + number2;
        float subtractionOfNumbers = number1 - number2;
        float multiplicationOfNumbers = number1 * number2;
        float divisionOfNumbers = number1 / number2;
        System.out.println("Please choose what operation do you want - (+)/(-)/(*)/(/): ");
        System.out.println(" 1 = + / 2 = - / 3 = * / 4 = /");
        int operation = scanner.nextInt();

        switch (operation) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("The sum of " +number1+ " and " +number2 + " is " +sumOfNumbers);
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("The subtraction of " +number1+ " and " +number2 + " is " +subtractionOfNumbers);
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("The multiplication  of " +number1+ " and " +number2 + " is " +multiplicationOfNumbers);
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("The division of " +number1+ " and " +number2 + " is " +divisionOfNumbers);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Why I'm getting crash when I'm trying to set float numbers?

Answer (score 0):

scanner.nextInt() returns an integer, not a float. Either type cast it to a float, or use scanner.nextFloat() instead

Comment: I tried nextFloat() and it worked. Are you sure you are entering numbers right?

Comment: yes, it still does not work. I dont know what is the problem, with int numbers everything works =/